# Generate Slide animation left wing when changing Sales

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

I have the following code in which I seek to generate an animation slide to the left and show the following QMainWindow and close the current one for which it uses a QPropertyAnimation within a function but it does not work here I leave the code:

Origin.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from segunda import MainTwo

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.Boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.Boton.setText("Press")
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.AnimaFunction)

        self.next = MainTwo()

    def AnimaFunction(self):
        self.anima = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.next.show(),b'geometry')
        self.anima.setDuration(1000)
        self.anima.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0,0,0,0))
        self.anima.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.next.geometry()))
        self.anima.start()


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

**Segunda.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel


class MainTwo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.setText("Soy la segunda ventana")
        self.Label.resize(200,200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the window to the `QPropertyAnimation`, instead you are passing the return of the show method that is `None` so the `QPropertyAnimation` will not do its job, considering the above the solution is:

```
def AnimaFunction(self):
    self.anima = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.next, b'geometry')
    self.anima.setDuration(1000)
    self.anima.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0,0,0,0))
    self.anima.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.next.geometry()))
    self.anima.start()
    self.next.show()
    self.hide()
```